# R grepl check if string contains all of our words

Tags: r, regex, nlp

Looking for a fast and non-verbose solution to check if a string contains **all** the elements of a vector of words given. I have come up with some ideas but have the feeling I am missing something especially since checking if the string contains **any** of the words has a very neat solution.

What I've tried:

```
# Example data
strings <- c(
  "never going to do this again",
  "never again", 
  "will repeat", 
  "never repeat", 
  "again tomorrow"
)

# Words we are looking for
ourWords <- c("never", "again")

# Check if string contains any of our words
grepl(paste0(ourWords, collapse = "|"), strings, , fixed = TRUE)
# Very neat solution but **not** what I am looking for    

# Check if string contains **all** of our words
grepl(ourWords[1], strings, fixed = TRUE) & 
  grepl(ourWords[2], strings, fixed = TRUE)
# This is verbose, not very scalable, and seems inefficient

# Even less efficient alternative
vapply(
  strsplit(strings, split = " "), 
  function(x)  sum(ourWords %in% x) == length(ourWords),
  logical(1)
)
```

Comment: `purrr::map(strings, stringi::stri_detect_fixed, ourWords) %>% purrr::map_lgl(all)` <= only putting this here due to one answerer deleting their similar one (and I mis-put this in Jan's answer before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of `sprintf` and multiple lookaheads:

```
strings <- c(
  "never going to do this again",
  "never again", 
  "will repeat", 
  "never repeat", 
  "again tomorrow"
)

ourWords <- c("never", "again")

regex <- paste0(sprintf("(?=.*%s)", ourWords), collapse = '')
strings[grepl(regex, strings, perl = TRUE)]
```

Which yields in this case

```
[1] "never going to do this again" "never again"
```

The idea here is to use multiple lookaheads.

Comment: @snoram: I'm pretty sure this is as close as it can get but I'd love to get convinced of the opposite :-)

Comment: Did another test and it does seem to beat my `vapply` by a big margin in terms of speed and should scale better than of the first.